# How to execute batch file from visual c# application

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

This might be a very specific question, but how do I execute a batch file in a sub folder above the c# application; I am trying to reference the batch file using a button:

```
    private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("test.bat");
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Command Prompt Commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"..\test.bat");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise I had to include "System.Diagnostics"